# Replacing words from an array. PHP

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have file and I want to replace one word with another like in array. For example I have `file.txt` and array:

```php
$arr = array(array("milk", "butter"), array("dog", "cat"))
```

So I want to replace all instances of "milk" with "butter" -- or all instances of "dogs" with "cats" in the text file.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Get the file content, replace the stuff and save it back?!

Answer (score 1):

This code replaces all occurrences of the first word of each inner array with the second word (the correspondent).

```
$txt = file_get_contents('file.txt'); //text example 'My dog loves milk. My cat loves butter.';
$words = array(array('milk', 'butter'), array('dog', 'cat'));

$result = $txt;
foreach($words as $word){
    $result = str_replace($word[0], $word[1], $result);
}

echo 'Before: ' . $txt;
echo '<br>';
echo 'After:   ' . $result;

file_put_contents('file2.txt', $result); // won't replace the file so you can see the difference.
```

Output:

> Before: My dog loves milk. My cat loves butter. 
>   After: My cat loves butter. My cat loves butter.

---

Notes:

- This is one way: it doesn't change one by the other. It replaces the first with the second;
- It's not checking for malformed;
- It must be of same case (case sensitive).

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this;

```
<?php
// get file content
$text = file_get_contents("file.txt");

$arr = array(array("milk", "butter"), array("dog", "cat"));

foreach($arr as $val){
    //replace text with your pattern
    $text = str_replace($val[0],$val[1],$text);
}

echo $text;
```